# VBS SendKeys is not sending "(" charactor

Tags: java, vbscript

am new here so please take it easy on me :). i have strange issue using this VB script below to enter data on a Notepad. The code i send using the "SendKeys" to the notepad is changed every time. i noticed the script working great except if the text i send is containing the "(" or ")" and if that happen i get error "Invalid procedure call or argument" and only have of the text print.

part of my code is below ( i couldn't attach it fully ):

```
Wscript.Sleep 300
objShell.SendKeys "zDYg8/bY)b6Ox$z"
```

Comment: Use {(}" for "(" and {)} for ")", vote up for great comment, not even needed anwser

Comment: @PSo the text is changing every time mate. i want something find the ( or ) on the text and fix it automatically. i don't want to do that manually every time. i hope you get what i mean.

Comment: I got what you mean, is it coming from outside or it generated automatically, i suggest you to write a function to look for braces the String and {} it out.

Comment: @PSo thats yes. the text on the file is coming from a batch file. then the batch will run the script as i need the SendKey functionality. its just the script fail if the variable after the sendkey was ( or ). too bad am only good at batching not VB that's why i need help on that part. thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

```
objShell.SendKeys "zDYg8/bY{)}b6Ox$z"
```

Read and follow [`SendKeys` method reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx):

> The SendKeys method uses some characters as modifiers of characters
>   (instead of using their face-values). This set of special characters
>   consists of parentheses, brackets, braces, and the:
>
> - plus sign       "+",
> - caret             "^",
> - percent sign "%",
> - and tilde       "~".
>
> Send these characters by enclosing them within braces "{}".

**Edit**. The answer was given for a particular string *literal*.

Use either [Replace Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx) or [Replace Method (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx) to modify a string *variable* to `SendKeys`-compliant format, e.g. as in the following code snippet:

```
sString = "zDYg(8/bY)b6Ox$z"
sStringToSend = Replace( Replace( sString, ")", "{)}"), "(", "{(}")
objShell.SendKeys sStringToSend
```

**Edit #2**: braces require special treatment, and must be handled first!

```
sStringGiven = "zDYg(8/bY)b6Ox$z"

' braces require special treatment, and must be handled first! 
sStringAux = ""
For ii = 1 To Len( sStringGiven)
  sChar = Mid( sStringGiven, ii, 1)
  Select Case sChar
    Case "{", "}"                                 ''' braces
      sStringAux = sStringAux & "{" & sChar & "}"
    Case Else
      sStringAux = sStringAux & sChar
  End Select
Next

' Then, special characters other than braces might be handled in any order
'       in a nested `replace` functions, or sequentially:
sStringAux    = Replace( Replace( sStringAux, "^", "{^}" ), "%", "{%}" )
sStringAux    = Replace( Replace( sStringAux, "+", "{+}" ), "~", "{~}" )
sStringAux    = Replace( Replace( sStringAux, "[", "{[}" ), "]", "{]}" )
sStringToSend = Replace( Replace( sStringAux, ")", "{)}" ), "(", "{(}" )
objShell.SendKeys sStringToSend
```

**Edit #3 - final solution**: omit `Replace` at all:

```
sStringGiven  = "zDYg(8/bY)b6Ox$z"
sStringToSend = ""
For ii = 1 To Len( sStringGiven)
  sChar = Mid( sStringGiven, ii, 1)
  Select Case sChar
  Case "{", "}", "(", ")", "[", "]", "^", "%", "+", "~"
    sStringToSend = sStringToSend & "{" & sChar & "}"
  Case Else
    sStringToSend = sStringToSend & sChar
  End Select
Next
objShell.SendKeys sStringToSend
```

Comment: thats i know thank you :). but how i tell my script to whenever it see that spceial chractor to all the {} to it.

Comment: thank you soo much! your lines was like a magic! it work like a charm. i learned something today thanks to you. i will include other special characters on that line so i get covered in future. too bad am new here otherwise i would  up vote your reply. :)