# Having problem using an operator(%) as a string

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, telnet

I have a batch file which runs the vbscript for the Telnet:

```
Option explicit
Dim oShell, str
set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Sendkeys "o confidential ip~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
str = "\%"
oShell.Sendkeys "E" & str & ".~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Sendkeys ".%c13,0;0.3.1%y~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Sendkeys "~"
```

When I run the batch file, the `%` character goes away and executes only

```
E.
.c13,0;0.3.1y
```

I want `%` to be used as a string after connecting to the telnet. I tried everything, it didn't seem to work.

Please help

Comment: As always, do NOT use `SendKeys` for telnet automation. Use a telnet command that is actually scriptable, like [`plink`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the [PuTTY suite](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).

Comment: You could also use Albert Yale's [Telnet Scripting Tool](http://support.moonpoint.com/downloads/windows/network/Telnet/tst10.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx):

> The plus sign "+", caret "^", percent sign "%", tilde "~", and parentheses "()" all have special meanings and must be enclosed within braces "{}".

So you should take care if, for example a `%` should be used as a literal in a 'sendkey' string, to enclose it with braces like `{%}`.

Comment: Perfect Sir, Thank You.
One more question. How do I save all the data that is displaying into a text or a csv file?

Comment: Sorry, I can‘t follow your question?

Comment: I get a wide range of data after running these commands. How do I save the data into a csv file or text file using vbs.

Comment: @prachi, please delete your comments and start a new question.  Your original question has already been answered.

Comment: It's been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175475/692942) more a less word for word, just with more detail.